# Error 'Constraint defines multiple validators for the type java.util.UUID", despite using only a single validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, lombok

I've discovered a weird Spring bug or at least a strange behavior when investigating a bug in our project. At runtime, whenever somebody called one particular endpoint, they got back error 500 with cause being:

> "ExistsSomeEntity defines multiple validators for the type java.util.UUID: com.example.validation.ExistsSomeEntityValidator, com.example.validation.ExistsSomeEntityValidator. Only one is allowed

The code of the method called by the endpoint is as such:

```
public void doSomethingWithAnEntity(@ExistsSomeEntity UUID id, WhatToDoRequest request) {
doSomething(id,request);
    }
```

Validation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ExistsSomeEntityValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ExistsSomeEntity {

    String message() default "{error.validation.ExistsSomeEntity.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator:

```
public class ExistsSomeEntityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ExistsSomeEntity, UUID> {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    private someDAO SomeEntityDAO;


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UUID id, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        checkForEntity(id, someDAO);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is only a single validator defined and there doesn't seem to be any obvious problem with it. This code was in use for about half a year without triggering this error...

After multiple attempts at finding the cause, I've noticed that the validation annotation is only ever used for parameter and never for a field, so I've modified it like this:

Validation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ExistsSomeEntityValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ExistsSomeEntity {

    String message() default "{error.validation.ExistsSomeEntity.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExistsSomeEntityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ExistsSomeEntity, UUID> {

    private final someDAO SomeEntityDAO;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UUID id, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        checkForEntity(id, someDAO);
    }
}
```

Getting rid of the @Autowired and using Lombok seems to have solved the issue, as the validation works as intended now, but I can't find any reason, why it would behave like that. I can't imagine that somebody not using Lombok would be prevented from using annotation validators in Spring. Any ideas?